# Warning whitelist doesn't work in Google closure compiler

Tags: google-closure-compiler

The manual says I can use:

```
 --warnings_whitelist_file VAL          : A file containing warnings to
                                          suppress. Each line should be of the
                                          form
                                          <file-name>:<line-number>?  <warning-d
                                          escription>
```

This is what my whitelist looks like:

```
ef-utils.js:1  Redeclared variable: ef
ef-utils.js:1  Variable ef first declared in externs-ko.js
ef-validation.js:1  Redeclared variable: ef
ef-validation.js:1  Variable ef first declared in externs-ko.js
```

And I am still getting warnings while compiling:

```
ef-utils.js:1: WARNING - Redeclared variable: ef
?var ef = (function (ns, ko) {
     ^

ef-utils.js:1: WARNING - Variable ef first declared in externs-ko.js
?var ef = (function (ns, ko) {
     ^

ef-validation.js:1: WARNING - Redeclared variable: ef
?var ef = (function (ns, ko) {
     ^

ef-validation.js:1: WARNING - Variable ef first declared in externs-ko.js
?var ef = (function (ns, ko) {
     ^
```

Answer (score 3):

I just toyed around with [the current WhitelistWarningsGuard](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/2b8d1fd6d66006e4cb62db9fd392dd358c867c5c/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/WhitelistWarningsGuard.java). I found out that

- Line numbers are completely ignored: they are stripped both from the input file and the encountered warnings.
- File names are formatted as they are for output, i.e. as they occur on the command line.
- There is a colon after the file name, followed by ***two*** spaces, followed by the message text without indicator of the severity (`WARNING`, `ERROR`).
- The main effect of the whitelist appears to be turning errors into warnings. So when applied to warnings, there will be *no effect at all*.
- The `WhitelistBuilder` mentioned by Tibos is there in the code, but I see no way to use it from the command line.

As it is, that feature appears to be mostly useless for my use cases…

Comment: It would be great if there was a way to completely ignore some errors using a file like this one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [WhitelistBuilder](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/WhitelistWarningsGuard.java#L212) to build the whitelist file. From the looks of it, you need absolute paths to the files, not relative.

Comment: This web page does not works anymore. Also, I can't find this tool anymore on the web.

Comment: ClosureCompiler is now on GitHub. The WhitelistBuilder class is [here](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/WhitelistWarningsGuard.java#L212), but it doesn't seem to be the preferred way to handle warnings anymore. I will update my answer when i determine the recommended process.

Answer (score 0):

As MvG correctly stated as this flag is implemented it's useless. Though, with pretty light changes to the compiler's code it can be turned to what we all expect from it: suppressing errors and warnings we don't want to see.

See details here: [Suppressing or resolving compiler errors in goog.base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29529993/supressing-or-resolving-compiler-errors-in-goog-base)